# SSRS report did not show two chart images until I refresh the browser

Tags: reporting-services, charts, report

I have a SSRS report that has a two chart images. After I moved the report from an old server(A server) to a new server(B server). The two chart images in the report didn't show until I refresh the browser.And after I refresh the browser, the two images both work fine.

The charts in the report both use the same shared data sources MyTest.rds. MyTest.rds is on another server(C server). And I just copy all the project in the old server to the new server and deploy it in the new server(B).

And now both A server and B server are work in the same Local Area Network(LNA).
Need I change anything else?

They have the same rd:DataSourceID, does it impact?

And when I click the chart image url, it will show
  **ASP.NET session has expired or could not be found**

Comment: It is strange, I copy all the file, but the old server work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Goto your **image properties** and check the URL. When the first time report loads it cannot find image in the location (URL) specified. Either **update the URL** or **save the images to the location where your URL is referring to.**

When you refresh the browser RS looks for the images in the same folder where the report exists. If the images exists then it will show the image

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but my image is not a real image, it is the report use the data(get from server C) to generate a image. It is a chart. Really thank you for your answer

Comment: Couple of other ways to attack this problem. 
**1**. Delete any unused parameters. Add **hard coded** default values to your **parameters** and run the report so if it works fine. If it does that means the issue is related to parameters.
**2**. **Remove the charts** and *replace it with table* from same dataset. Now verify if the report shows data or not.

Comment: Hi, The table can show the data, in the report I have some other tables, they all work fine